# How to set a breakpoint in function which can be detected by gdb

Tags: gdb

I want to debug a C++ function which  is called at the time of system boot, thus by the time I manually connect gdb and set a breakpoint the function has already been called and returned.

I tried to set an infinite loop, but the system seems to have optmised it and moved forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried to set an infinite loop, but the system seems to have optmised it and moved forward.

If you are going to be effective at debugging, first thing you need to learn is to confirm your assumptions.

The "the system seems to have ..." is not an acceptable assumption, you need to *confirm* that this is indeed what has happened, using GDB `disas` command.

It is also *impossible* for compiler to optimize out an infinite loop like this:

```
volatile int gdb_attached = 0;
while (!gdb_attached) {
  printf("Waiting for gdb to attach\n");
  sleep(1);
}
```

If you put a loop like above into your function, it is guaranteed (assuming your compiler is not exceptionally buggy) that your function (if it is called *at all*) will not return until you attach GDB to your process, and set `gdb_attached` to non-zero value from GDB.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to use `gdb` on a running process.

If you are using `g++` as your compiler, you can use `-O0` flag to avoid optimization. Or do something in the loop which compiler can't optimize. e.g. Changing value of variable outside the loop or print some random stuff to the output.

Also, a busy waiting process may not be a good idea because it waste lots of CPU resources. Sleep it until you can debug is another option.

Comment: thanx owenwater...putting to sleep is a better option.